# SAP authentication with WCF Adapter Service project

Tags: wcf, adapter, biztalk, saprfc

I've been experimenting with the BizTalk Adapter Pack, specifically with the SAP stuff.

I'm able to connect to SAP and run an RFC from a client app (e.g. Console, Windows, Web site) using the SAP binding directly, no problem at all. I've also got it all working in BizTalk Server 2009 using orchestration, send port, receive port, etc.

However, I want to expose SAP functionality to internal users as a standard HTTP web service, without requiring them to have the SAP binding stuff installed on their PC.

So, I created a "WCF Adapter Service" project in Visual Studio, and followed the wizard. I then created a standard web app for the client end, and added a proxy using "Add service reference". It all worked OK, in that it found the service and added the proxy code, but when I try to invoke the service I get the error **SapErrorMessage=Incomplete logon data**.

What I don't know how to do is pass SAP credentials from my client web app to the Basic HTTP service and then on the the SAP binding. If I put the SAP credentials into the SAP connection string it all works OK, but this is not very secure and also I want to supply the credentials from the client (i.e. ask the user to provide their SAP credentials).

In some examples I've seen, e.g. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788594(BTS.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788594%28BTS.10%29.aspx), the SAP credentials are passed in HTTP headers. Unfortunately, all the examples I've seen of this go on to show how to invoke the service from SharePoint, where there's a dialog window for setting the headers. I'm not using SharePoint! I've tried adding a "" section to my client endpoint configuration, but this didn't seem to work.

So, what is the recommended way to pass SAP credentials to a Basic HTTP web service created via the "WCF Adapter Service" wizard?

For information, this is the relevant part of the web.config on my client web app:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="RfcEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://xxxxxx/SAP_Service_1/Rfc.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RfcEndpoint" contract="ServiceReference1.Rfc" name="RfcEndpoint">
            <headers>
                <SAP_Username>username</SAP_Username>
                <SAP_Password>password</SAP_Password>
            </headers>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And this is the web.config generated by the WCF Adapter Service project wizard:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="customServiceBehavior" name="RfcClient">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="customEndpointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RfcClientBindingConfig" name="RfcEndpoint" contract="Rfc"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="customEndpointBehavior">
                    <endpointBehavior usernameHttpHeader="SAP_Username" passwordHttpHeader="SAP_Password" adapterSecurityBridgeType="HTTPUsernamePassword"/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="customServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <serviceCredentials type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterServiceCredentials, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                    <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterServiceAuthorizationManager, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                        <authorizationPolicies>
                            <add policyType="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterAuthorizationPolicy, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                        </authorizationPolicies>
                    </serviceAuthorization>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="endpointBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterEndpointBehavior, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="RfcClientBindingConfig">
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <sapBinding>
                <binding name="SAPBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" enableBizTalkCompatibilityMode="false" receiveIdocFormat="Typed" enableSafeTyping="false" generateFlatFileCompatibleIdocSchema="true" maxConnectionsPerSystem="50" enableConnectionPooling="true" idleConnectionTimeout="00:15:00" flatFileSegmentIndicator="SegmentDefinition" enablePerformanceCounters="false" autoConfirmSentIdocs="false" acceptCredentialsInUri="true" padReceivedIdocWithSpaces="false" sncLibrary="" sncPartnerName="" rfcAllowStartProgram="">
                    <dataTypesBehavior datsMinToDateTime="NULL" datsMaxToDateTime="NULL" invalidDatsToDateTime="ERROR" emptyDatsToDateTime="0001-01-01T00:00:00" emptyTimsToDateTime="0001-01-01T00:00:00" dateTimeMaxToDats="99991231" dateTimeMinToDats="00010101" timsMaxToDateTime="NULL" invalidTimsToDateTime="ERROR" dateTimeMaxToTims="235959" dateTimeMinToTims="000000" invalidNumcToInt="0" emptyNumcToInt="0" dateTimeNullToDats="SKIP" dateTimeNullToTims="SKIP"/>
                </binding>
            </sapBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="sap://CLIENT=300;LANG=EN;@a/XXXXXX/00?RfcSdkTrace=False&amp;AbapDebug=False" binding="sapBinding" bindingConfiguration="SAPBinding" contract="Rfc" name="SAPBinding_Rfc"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm a bit new to WCF, so any help or pointers gratefully received!

Thanks

Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an even easier solution!

WCF is happy to send the Username / Password credentials in the message body providing the message is protected. Don't know why I didn't think of it before, but setting security like this:

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
```

means that Rohit's suggestion now works.

So, the service web.config expects the credentials in the message and uses transport security:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="customServiceBehavior" name="RfcClient">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="customEndpointBehavior"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RfcClientBindingConfig"
                    name="RfcEndpoint" contract="Rfc" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="customEndpointBehavior">
                    <endpointBehavior adapterSecurityBridgeType="ClientCredentialUsernamePassword" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="customServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <serviceCredentials type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterServiceCredentials, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="servername" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterServiceAuthorizationManager, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                        <authorizationPolicies>
                            <add policyType="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterAuthorizationPolicy, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                        </authorizationPolicies>
                    </serviceAuthorization>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="endpointBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterEndpointBehavior, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="RfcClientBindingConfig">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <sapBinding>
                <binding name="SAPBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" enableBizTalkCompatibilityMode="false"
                    receiveIdocFormat="Typed" enableSafeTyping="false" generateFlatFileCompatibleIdocSchema="true"
                    maxConnectionsPerSystem="50" enableConnectionPooling="true"
                    idleConnectionTimeout="00:15:00" flatFileSegmentIndicator="SegmentDefinition"
                    enablePerformanceCounters="false" autoConfirmSentIdocs="false"
                    acceptCredentialsInUri="false" padReceivedIdocWithSpaces="false"
                    sncLibrary="" sncPartnerName="" rfcAllowStartProgram="">
                    <dataTypesBehavior datsMinToDateTime="NULL" datsMaxToDateTime="NULL"
                        invalidDatsToDateTime="ERROR" emptyDatsToDateTime="0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                        emptyTimsToDateTime="0001-01-01T00:00:00" dateTimeMaxToDats="99991231"
                        dateTimeMinToDats="00010101" timsMaxToDateTime="NULL" invalidTimsToDateTime="ERROR"
                        dateTimeMaxToTims="235959" dateTimeMinToTims="000000" invalidNumcToInt="0"
                        emptyNumcToInt="0" dateTimeNullToDats="SKIP" dateTimeNullToTims="SKIP" />
                </binding>
            </sapBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="sap://CLIENT=300;LANG=EN;@a/XXXXXX/00?RfcSdkTrace=False&amp;AbapDebug=False"
                binding="sapBinding" bindingConfiguration="SAPBinding" contract="Rfc"
                name="SAPBinding_Rfc" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And the client web.config is similarly configured:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="RfcEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://servername/SAP_Service_BASIC/Rfc.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RfcEndpoint" contract="ServiceReference1.Rfc" name="RfcEndpoint"/>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then the client code is simply:

```
string cust = "12345";
string po = "12345";
string salesOrg = "1234";
string transGroup = "0";

BAPIORDERS[] orders = new BAPIORDERS[0];
BAPIRETURN ret = new BAPIRETURN();

using (RfcClient client = new RfcClient("RfcEndpoint"))
{
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

    try
    {
        ret = client.BAPI_SALESORDER_GETLIST(cust, null, null, null, po, null, salesOrg, transGroup, ref orders);

        GridView1.DataSource = orders;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        client.Close();

    }
    catch (CommunicationException ex)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(ex.Message);
        if (ex.InnerException != null) sb.Append("~" + ex.InnerException.Message);
        Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
        client.Abort();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        client.Abort();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        client.Abort();
        throw;
    }

}
```

Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Got it working at last!

First, I needed to get the SAP username and password added as HTTP headers in the request. I tried the simple solution of editing the config file first, as some have suggested:

```
<endpoint ....
  <headers>
    <HeaderName1>Header Value 1</HeaderName1>
    <HeaderName2>Header Value 2</HeaderName2>
  </headers>
</endpoint>
```

But this does not add HTTP headers, or at least I wasn't able to get it to work.

I looked at the excellent article here http://ericphan.info/blog/2010/6/3/adding-custom-http-header-to-all-wcf-requests.html, which explains how to user a MessageInspector to add HTTP headers to the outgoing request. It works brilliantly, but headers are defined in the config file. I needed a way to set the headers in code. Perhaps there would be a way of adapting this code, but I'm not that clever!

Instead, I found some other examples and distilled it down to this:

```
using (RfcClient client = new RfcClient("RfcEndpoint"))
{

    try
    {
        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
        {

            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty;
            if (OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name))
            {
                httpRequestProperty = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
            }
            else
            {
                httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            }
            httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("SAP_Username", "dXNlcm5hbWU=");
            httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("SAP_Password", "cGFzc3dvcmQ=");
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

            ret = client.BAPI_SALESORDER_GETLIST(cust, null, null, null, po, null, salesOrg, transGroup, ref orders);

            GridView1.DataSource = orders;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        client.Close();

        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    }
    catch (CommunicationException ex)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(ex.Message);
        if (ex.InnerException != null) sb.Append("~" + ex.InnerException.Message);
        Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
        client.Abort();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        client.Abort();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        client.Abort();
        throw;
    }

}
```

For completeness, this is the web.config file for the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="customServiceBehavior" name="RfcClient">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="customEndpointBehavior"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RfcClientBindingConfig"
                    name="RfcEndpoint" contract="Rfc" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="customEndpointBehavior">
                    <endpointBehavior usernameHttpHeader="SAP_Username" passwordHttpHeader="SAP_Password"
                        adapterSecurityBridgeType="HTTPUsernamePassword" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="customServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <serviceCredentials type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterServiceCredentials, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="servername" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterServiceAuthorizationManager, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                        <authorizationPolicies>
                            <add policyType="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterAuthorizationPolicy, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                        </authorizationPolicies>
                    </serviceAuthorization>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="endpointBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.AdapterEndpointBehavior, Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="RfcClientBindingConfig">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <sapBinding>
                <binding name="SAPBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" enableBizTalkCompatibilityMode="false"
                    receiveIdocFormat="Typed" enableSafeTyping="false" generateFlatFileCompatibleIdocSchema="true"
                    maxConnectionsPerSystem="50" enableConnectionPooling="true"
                    idleConnectionTimeout="00:15:00" flatFileSegmentIndicator="SegmentDefinition"
                    enablePerformanceCounters="false" autoConfirmSentIdocs="false"
                    acceptCredentialsInUri="false" padReceivedIdocWithSpaces="false"
                    sncLibrary="" sncPartnerName="" rfcAllowStartProgram="">
                    <dataTypesBehavior datsMinToDateTime="NULL" datsMaxToDateTime="NULL"
                        invalidDatsToDateTime="ERROR" emptyDatsToDateTime="0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                        emptyTimsToDateTime="0001-01-01T00:00:00" dateTimeMaxToDats="99991231"
                        dateTimeMinToDats="00010101" timsMaxToDateTime="NULL" invalidTimsToDateTime="ERROR"
                        dateTimeMaxToTims="235959" dateTimeMinToTims="000000" invalidNumcToInt="0"
                        emptyNumcToInt="0" dateTimeNullToDats="SKIP" dateTimeNullToTims="SKIP" />
                </binding>
            </sapBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="sap://CLIENT=300;LANG=EN;@a/XXXXXX/00?RfcSdkTrace=False&amp;AbapDebug=False"
                binding="sapBinding" bindingConfiguration="SAPBinding" contract="Rfc"
                name="SAPBinding_Rfc" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And for the web client app:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors />
    <extensions />
    <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="RfcEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
      <endpoint address="https://servername/SAP_Service_HTTP/Rfc.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RfcEndpoint"
      contract="ServiceReference1.Rfc" name="RfcEndpoint" >
      </endpoint>>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This uses transport security (SSL) to protect the headers, but it works without also.

Note the final twist to the exercise. The HTTP header values needed to be Base64 encoded! I've no idea why, but it must be that the SAP adapter is expecting them to be.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't adding the following to the client app  work for you?

```
RfcClient client = new RfcClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myusername";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "mypassword";
```

Comment: Rohit. Thanks for your suggestion. I did try this but initially couldn't get it to work.

However, I have now, by switching to wsHttpBinding and using a service certificate. It seems that WCF is not happy to transmit credentials "in the clear". By using message security, i.e. credentials transmitted in the message itself, together with message encryption using a service certificate, it worked.

The only two issues were granting the IIS process identity access to the certificate private key and having the self-generated certificate CA in the trusted people store.

Comment: However, I'm still keen to find a solution using basicHttpBinding. From what I've read so far, I should be able to use adapterSecurityBridgeType=HTTPUsernamePassword on the service side and supply the SAP username/password in the HTTP request headers. I'll keep trying to find a solution and report back if I do.